# find view by id works only on some devices

Tags: android, device

I am trying to build an android application.
The application requires android 2.2 and Google Apis (for Google Maps).

- When I launch the application on a 2.2 Android emulator, it works.
- When I launch the application on a Galaxy S II with Android 2.3.7
  (Cyanogen mod) it works.
- But when I launch the application on a HP
  Touchpad with the same version of the Cyanogen mod it fails at the
  beginning after a findViewById returned null!

I have rebuilt the project, cleaned it etc... and it didn't change any thing.
Any idea of what could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: I don't do mind-reading on Mondays. Perhaps posting the snippet of code which crashes, your layout file and logcat output might help.

Comment: @MisterSquonk yes I should have done that. But I didn't realize I had two layouts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using alternative layouts? i.e. 'res/layout-large', 'res/layout-small', etc.

If so, make sure the view you are trying to find appears in all of the different layouts.

Comment: Possible but without knowing more about the OP's layout files it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Of course, but if every person asking a question gave all the information required to answer it then it wouldn't be very fun would it!

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that I did several version of the layout!